# Sorting an array based on the number of occurrences

Tags: java, arrays

Hi i'm trying to sort an array based on the number of occurrences of the value in the array. So if my array `int[] a = new int[]{9,2,4,8,9,4,3,2,8,1,2,7,2,5};`my array count should be: count[i-1] and based on the value of the array my count array looks like this: `1 4 1 2 1 0 1 2 2` so `count[0] = 1` stores the count for 1. `count[1] =4` and stores the count for 2, `count[2] = 1`stores the count for 3, and `count[8] =2` stores the number of occurrences for 9. My count should be `count[i-1]` to store the number of the number of occurrences and based on the number of occurrences i should sort the array. First question, i am having trouble storing the counts of occurrences of the array a into the count array. And based on the number of occurrences how do i go about storing the array.

Comment: If the upper bound of a[i] is moderately smaller then I would suggest Counting sort

Comment: So far I only see the requirements. What trouble do you actually have implementing it?

Comment: @ZiadHalabi Yeah. that may be the solution. But I felt that's complicated. Simply counting sort will do. Just a thought

Comment: @sathiyaseelan OP has a problem *storing the counts of occurrences of the array a into the count array*, I'm not sure if he/she could implement counting sort.

Comment: Please provide your current code and explain what's your *trouble storing the counts of occurrences of the array a into the count array*. In this way, we'll be able to provide the exact help on your problem.

Comment: Yes. As @LuiggiMendoza says, if you post your current code, we can help to fix the problem or else to do some optimization if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to go through you array, storing how many times each number appears. Assume the array can contain elements only from `1` to `k`, so we need a `count` array that can store `k` elements:

```
int k = 9;
int[] count = new int[k];
```

Note that this array will be initialized with the default value `0` at each position, which takes `O(k)` time and space to do, so it is equivalent to:

```
int[] count = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

So the initial count is `0` for all elements.

Now we count the elements from the array.

For example:

```
int[] a = new int[]{9,2,4,8,9,4,3,2,8,1,2,7,2,5};
// Go through each element of this array:
int n = a.length
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Add 1 to the corresponding position in the count array.
    int position = a[i] - 1;
    count[position]++;
}
```

This takes `O(n)` time, and will result in:

```
count = {1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2}
```

After we've done this, the array is actually sorted. We can see this is true by doing:

```
int[] sorted = new int[n];
int h = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; j++) {
        // Sum 1 to i to get the original number
        sorted[h++] = i + 1;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));
```

Which also takes `O(n)` time and space, and outputs:

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

So the total time and space complexity for this algorithm is `O(n + k)`, that means it runs linearly in the number of items plus the difference between the maximum and minimum key values.

Comment: Can this sorting algorithm be optimized?

Comment: I don't think so, since it is already `O(n + k)`. I updated the answer to show that.

Comment: i understood it clearly. Thanks very much.